# what code do i need for making my LoginActivity shown once if the user is already Logged In?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

where I can put `SharedPreference` in my working progress thesis project. I'm having a simple trouble in here. here is my sample code for `loginActivity` im still wondering on how/where I put the other SharedPreference code.

Im having trouble with one time login using SharedPreference .I don't know where do i put the code. i searched thru the net but nothing works for me i know i am having trouble placing the code but i can't fix it.

```
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);


            auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

            progressBar = findViewById(R.id.prgBar);
            btnLogin = findViewById(R.id.user_login);
            userEmail = findViewById(R.id.user_email);
            userPwd = findViewById(R.id.user_password);
            btnReg = findViewById(R.id.user_reg);

            btnReg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this, RegisterActivity.class));
                }
            });


            btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    String email = userEmail.getText().toString();
                    final String password = userPwd.getText().toString();

                    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(email)) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enter email address!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        return;
                    }

                    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(password)) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enter password!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        return;
                    }


                    //authenticate user

                    auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                            .addOnCompleteListener(LoginActivity.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                                    // If sign in fails, display a message to the user. If sign in succeeds
                                    // the auth state listener will be notified and logic to handle the
                                    // signed in user can be handled in the listener.


                                    if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                                        // there was an error
                                        if (password.length() < 6) {
                                            userPwd.setError(getString(R.string.minimum_password));
                                        } else {
                                            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, getString(R.string.auth_failed), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                        }

                                    } else {


                                        Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, userInterface.class);
                                        startActivity(intent);
                                        finish();

                                    }
                                }
                            });

                }
            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: you should use `sharedpreference` for that . for detail information .please google it.

Comment: i did but im having trouble placing it, it doesn't work properly @Tej

Comment: then please change the title of your question  and mentioned what trouble you are facing

Comment: you didn't tell us what you want.

Comment: Thank you so much, im so sorry too for making it difficult

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using Firebase-authentication, you do not need to use `SharedPreferences` to see if the user had logged in before.

You can do this, example in the `Splash Activity //first activity`

```
FirebaseUser user=FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
if(user!=null){
     //Signed in, go to home activity
    Intent i=new Intent(SplashActivity.this,HomeActivity.class);
    startActivity(i);
  } 
  else{
      //not logged in
      Intent intent=new Intent(SplashActivity.this,LoginActivity.class);
      startActivity(intent);
     }
```